# Cómo puedo cambiar dimensiones de casa (java)

Tags: java

Hola he hecho un código que crea una casa usando vacío, el problema es que quiero poner más vacío a los lados y cambiar el tamaño de ellos. Pero cuando intento poner otro utilizando el vacío, las ventanas cambian de posiciones. ¿Qué debo hacer?

```
void square(int x,int y,int size)
{
  rect(x,y,size,size);
}

void triangle(int x,int y,int size) 
{
  fill(255);
  int middle = size/2;
  line(x,y,x+size,y);
  line(x,y,x+middle,y-middle);
  line(x+size,y,x+middle,y-middle);
}

void circle(int x,int y,int size)
{
  ellipse(x,y,size,size);
}

void roof(int x,int y,int size)
{
  int middle = size/2;
  triangle(x,y,size);
  circle(x+middle,y-middle/3,size/4);
}

void house(int x,int y,int size)
{
  rect(x,y,size,size);
  rect(x*1.6,y*1.1,size*0.25,size*0.25);
  rect(x*1.6,y*1.4,size*0.25,size*0.25);
  rect(x*1.1,y*1.6,size*0.25,size*0.4);
}

void mansion(int x,int y,int size)
{
  roof(x,y,size);
  house(x,y,size);
}

void setup()
{
  size(1000,1000);
  fill(255);
  mansion(80,80,80);
}
```

Comment: Tanto en el título de la pregunta como en la etiqueta, se indica que es una pregunta sobre Java, sin embargo el código puesto no es Java. ¿Quizás querías decir Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

El problema que veo en tu código es que las coordenadas (x, y) de las ventanas no deberían ser un producto de las coordenadas iniciales, sino una suma, ya que se trata de una traslación desde el origen. Así es como quedaría el código para pintarlas, teniendo en cuenta la proporción:

```
void house(int x,int y,int size)
{
  rect(x,y,size,size);
  rect(x + (size*0.5), y + (size*0.1), size*0.25, size*0.25);
  rect(x + (size*0.5), y + (size*0.5), size*0.25, size*0.25);
  rect(x + (size*0.1), y + (size*0.4), size*0.25, size*0.4);
}
```

Los valores que multiplican a "size" los he metido a ojo. Ajústalos para conseguir el resultado deseado.